# 404 error even after mapping /resource/** to /resource/ in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have mapped my resources `locust.js` and `locust.css` files to the folder, resources, as shown in the image:

[image]

<sup>*Directory Structure*</sup>

The `mvc-config.xml` file has the following configuration settings:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
             <!-- Example: a logical view name of 'showMessage' is mapped to '/WEB-INF/jsp/showMessage.jsp' -->
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

I am getting 404 error when I try to load the `locust.js` and `locust.css` files. The jsp files are rendering properly.

Any clue where am I wrong here?

Comment: What is your requested URL? `http://localhost:8080/resources/locust.js` or `http://localhost:8080/locust.js`?

Comment: `src/main/resources` is part of your classpath, it is the root of your classpath. So at runtime there is no `/resources`/

Comment: My requested URL is http://localhost:8080/SSGuide/resources/locust.js

Comment: When I replace <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" /> with <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/" /> and change the location of locust.js and locust.css to folder /web-app then the locust.js and locust.css gets loaded!! I guess M.Deinum is right but I still do not understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Spring was unable load the locust.js and locust.css files because my root ("/") folder was pointing to "webapp" folder and so spring was unable to resolve the path as the resources were outside the 'webapp' folder.
Thanks.